# Excel column heads on row 2 of export from ColdFusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion, export, styling

I want the table exported from ColdFusion to Excel with the headers below to show column headers on Row 2 of the spreadsheet, with filtering turned on when first viewed.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/msexcel">
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
```

How do I set styles and XML specs to obtain this result?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to just create a simple spreadsheet with the feature you want in Excel. Then save it as HTML and view the source to see how what code is used.

This is a basic example I created by doing exactly that. The main properties that control filtering are `autofilter` and `autofilterrange`:

```
<!--- sample data --->
<cfset someQuery = queryNew("")>
<cfset queryAddColumn(someQuery, "ID", listToArray("10,22,14,51,62"))>
<cfset queryAddColumn(someQuery, "Title", listToArray("AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE"))>

<!--- generate --->
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/msexcel">
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<!--- adjust filter range according to number of columns in query ---> 
<tr><td x:autofilter="all" x:autofilterrange="$A$1:$B$1">ID</td>
    <td x:autofilter="all">Title</td>
</tr>
<cfoutput query="someQuery">
    <tr><td>#ID#</td>
        <td>#Title#</td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```